Not able to fetch specific partition data from tKafkaInput in Talend
We have a Kafka topic distributed across 3 partitions, and I need to fetch/read data from partition 1 in one job and partition 2 in another job. I have tried using several Kafka parameters in the advanced settings of the tKafkaInput component but have not been able to successfully retrieve data from specific partitions.
Could you kindly provide the correct expressions or parameters that I should use in the properties to achieve this?
I have give some parameters in advance setting but not works

Partitions cannot be specified in the consumer config

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html
Or in Talend https://help.qlik.com/talend/en-US/components/7.3/kafka/tkafkainput-standard-properties

In order to specify partitions in the consumer API, would require an assign API call, where I assume Talend is doing subscribe API

I understand you mentioned that partitions cannot be specified in the consumer configuration and that Talend might use the subscribe API. However, I need clarification on:
Assign vs. Subscribe API: Can you explain the difference between the assign and subscribe API calls? How does it affect data retrieval from partitions?
tKafkaInput Configuration: Can you provide examples or parameters for configuring the tKafkaInput component to read from a specific partition?
Workaround Solutions: If direct partition fetching isn’t supported, are there any workarounds or best practices?

I'm referring to the API documentation functions of Kafka consumer itself... subscribe simply doesn't accept a list of explicit partitions, whereas assign does. The workaround (other than not using talend) would be to use some consumer+producer pairing to read all partitions, then filter, then output to a new, single partition topic
